# Wifi ? (questionmark)

Tags: wireless

Why do I get this on the wifi symbol?

wifisymbol with an questionmark

[image: wifisymbol with an questionmark over it]

Comment: which version and flavour of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the connection is established, despite of the icon?

Comment: Check your connection. Also possible faulty network card. Happens with wired connection too. Reset your network card;  reboot the laptop or the router.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Connectivity Checking**
- Set it **OFF**
- Restart your WiFi connection